# How to pass the parameter in BootstrapDialog.show({ }) popup

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, ngx-bootstrap-modal

I'm using BootstrapDialog to show a popup. I want to pass a parameter. I'm using data attribute. My piece of code is:

```
BootstrapDialog.show({
     closable: false,
     title: "This is my popup",
     message: $('<div></div>').load(url),
     data: $('#divResourcePlanName').text($scope.ResourcePlanDetail.ResourcePlan.Name)
});
```

Still I'm not able to get the `$scope.ResourcePlanDetail.ResourcePlan.Name` value in my HTML.

Comment: You should create a directive for this.

Answer (score 1):

You need a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) to make it work fine. `data` expects an object. You don't need `data` here to make it work right. You should avoid DOM-Bindings at all. Only use DOM bindings inside your directive.

> **What are Directives?**
>   At a high level, directives are markers on a DOM element (such as an attribute, element name, comment or CSS class) that tell AngularJS's HTML compiler ($compile) to attach a specified behavior to that DOM element (e.g. via event listeners), or even to transform the DOM element and its children.

#### View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.4/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.4/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <button my-dialog message="someMessage">
        Open dialog
      </button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Dialog Template

```
<h1>{{ message }}</h1>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.someMessage = 'Hello World';
});

myApp.directive('myDialog', function ($templateRequest, $compile) {
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      message: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on('click', function () {
        $templateRequest("dialog.html").then(function(html){
            BootstrapDialog.show({
              title: 'Say-hello dialog',
              message: $compile(html)(scope),
          });
        });
      })
    }
  }
});
```

**> [demo plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OgDU1KPhx98K7qv9wgMi?p=preview)**